# Add to link with an id

Tags: php, function, url

I'm wanting to add an id to the end of a url.
The expected url I want is:https://crm.mysite.com/Accounts/7227227

This is what I have so far:

```
public function getCustomerRepositoryUrl()
    {
        $link = 'https://crm.mysite.com/Accounts/';
        $crmId = $this->contact->getCustomerRepositoryIdentifier();//this returns the id needed
        $link .= crmId;
        return $this->$link;
    }
```

Comment: Why `return $this->$link`?  Why not just `return $link`, as that's how you've been referring to the variable all along?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to return `$link` and not `$this->link`.

If your code didn't give you an error you *really should* turn on PHP errors because not seeing errors when developing is like driving blind.

Comment: Yes, this was it. Thank you @Evert, I appreciate it!